# TypeScript types for Node.js file descriptor

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

If I open a file like so:

```
const fd = fs.openSync('<file-path>','r+');
```

it returns a file descriptor. Does anyone know what the typescript typings is for fd? How can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just opened up

```
node_modules/@types/node
```

and searched for "openSync", here it is:

```
export function openSync(path: string | Buffer, flags: string | number, mode?: number): number;
```

I just happen to know that openSync returns a file descriptor, however, I didn't know that an fd was just an number/integer.

Comment: That would be exactly what's documented in the Node.js API: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_opensync_path_flags_mode

Comment: indeed, although on occasion the docs are not perfect, the format is not super consistent :) that's ok, I still like the node.js docs.

Comment: the key part, homie, was knowing that  fs.openSync returned a file descriptor, the rest was "easy"